# Kotlin Layout Doesn't Fit the Screen

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout, scrollview

[PROBLEM IMAGE CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xOn9.png)

My layout doesn't **fit** the screen How do I solve this? Thank you for your help. I was trying to show my data from `ViewModel`. 
**This is my XML code here**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailTopText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detailImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailDesText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The problem is not in this layout, but in how you've set up the action bar and the window. We need to see your Activity code.

Comment: It's a fragment and there isn't any code about action bar in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your new layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailTopText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detailImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/flatwoods_img_btn_" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailDesText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView2" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks this is good but I can't see first textview and top of imageview, do you think my android studio has a bug ?

Comment: Select the view from the component tree and then in the Attributes Panel add constriants according to your need.

Comment: I added this code "android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"" to constraintlayout and it worked,thanks Haris Muntazir have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Try setting margin top in your linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add paddingTop or marginTop properties with action bar size to the `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but can't see little bit top of my top textview